# Help with django filters

Tags: django, django-templates

I am have a list of "Entries"

I want to get the first entry in the list's "title".

In the template I tried writing

```
{{ Entries|first.title }}
```

But it results in an error.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing a loop or doing it in the view?

Comment: ... What? Write out in Python what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you passed a list of Entries to the template under the name 'Entries',

```
{{ Entries.0.title }}
```

will give you the title of the first entry in the list. The `first` filter isn't the shortest path to where you want to go in this case.